# How to collect data from Inputs?

Tags: jquery, input, var

```
<input id="e-1" type="text"/> 
<input id="e-2" type="text"/>
<button id="go">go</button>
```

This is input validate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var code ="";
var c1="";
var c2="";
  $('input#e-1').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      c1 = "Error 400 - " + $('input#e-1').val();  
   });
  $('input#e-2').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      c2 = "Error 404 - " + $('input#e-2').val();  
   });

});
```

How to collect values from all Inputs in a `var code ="";` and then display this value by clicking a button to `<textarea></textarea>`?

**I made a mistake, and how to make different signatures for each line, but not everywhere Error 400? check updated code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery data feature:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      $(this).data('my-error-codes', "Error " + $(this).data('error-name') + "- " + $(this).val());
   });

 $('#go').click(function(){
   var code = "";
   $("input").each(function(){
    code += $(this).data('my-error-codes') + "\n" || '';
   });
   $('#textarea').html(code);
 });

});
```

Html:

```
 <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
 <input id="e-1" type="text" data-error-name="400" /> 
 <input id="e-2" type="text" data-error-name="404" /> 
 <button id="go">go</button>
```

JsBin:
http://jsbin.com/ubomeq/

http://jsbin.com/ubomeq/edit#source

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
$(document).ready(function(){
var code ="";
  $('input#e-1').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      code  += "Error 400 - " + $('input#e-1').val();  
   });
  $('input#e-2').bind('blur keyup',function() {
      code   += "Error 400 - " + $('input#e-2').val();  
   });
  $('#go').click(function(){
    $('#textarea').html(code);
  });


});
```

Comment: this will display "code" in textarea, but "code" it only value of #e-1

Comment: I already tried that, but get: "Error 400 - 2Error 400 - 11Error 400 - 111Error 400 - 111Error 400 - 22Error 400 - 222Error 400 - 222"

Comment: so what you want...you want to separate your errors by some identifier

Comment: then you can go wd `Ghommey` answer